# Copy a file to a Docker container just before starting it

Tags: linux, docker

I know that you can copy a file from host to a running Docker container using `docker cp`, but in my case I want to copy it just before starting the docker container. How can I do that?

Note that I don't want this file in my built docker image, so I cannot copy it at build time even. Another way is to use mounted volumes (with `-v`), but I don't want that either.

Comment: Why don't you want to use mounted volumes ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
docker create mycon
docker cp /myfiles/file mycon:/path/file
docker start mycon
```

Comment: That is brilliant! What also worked for me is to start the container, copy file to it and then restart it, by using docker restart <container_name>.

Comment: yes that will work also , but your question was about copîng before starting :)