# Need to a create file in /dev path in non-root container on startup

Tags: docker

I am trying to bring up a container which would have a socket file created in /dev partition (during startup before any entrypoint could function)

Now I understand that /dev directory in a container is mounted on tmpfs mount and is dynamically created. So I cannot create this socket file as part of my build. (Even if I create this in build, the directory would be removed anyways post the build).

The container I bring up (run) is with non-root user (testrun) and also has no-new-privileges option passed in run as shown below.

`docker run \
    --rm \
    -it -d \
    --name cont_testdev_1 \
    --security-opt no-new-privileges \
    --cap-drop all \
    --user testrun:test \
    testdev`

I have tried or considered following options:

1) Creating this socket file in my entrypoint script. This is not possible in my case as /dev by default has only read permission for non-root users and my container starts as user 'testrun'. Also I cannot perform a sudo as no-new-priveleges is provided.

Any way to create /dev with 777 permissions in the containers ?

2) Try and manually create the /dev partition with enough permissions by using --tmpfs option during run as shown below.

`--mount type=tmpfs,destination=/dev,tmpfs-mode=0777`

But this causes following failure in container init.

`docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:424: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:114: reopening /dev/null inside container caused \\\"Failed to open /dev/null - open /dev/null: permission denied\\\"\"": unknown.`

Not sure how to overcome this.

3) Create this socket file in host and mount it into the container during run. But I need this socket file as tmpfs mount because there would be multiple instances of the container and I dont want to create multiple socket files in the host's filesystem.

4) Using ACLs and assign access to testrun for the /dev folder during image build. But as /dev folder gets deleted post build, the ACLs disappear as well.

5) Linux kernel modules and udev rules are ruled out as there is no kernel in the containers and the host' kernel is what is used.

The obvious question that many would ask is why not create the socket file in any other path - this is the last option I am left with as it would mean lots of handling changes from my side. I just want to hear expert opinions before I take this option.

So my question to the experts here is, is there any option where such custom files can be created with enough permissions (mainly in dynamically created folders like /dev) when the container comes up ?

I would be really thankful for any help or suggestions.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771529/copy-a-file-to-a-docker-container-just-before-starting-it/57771688#57771688

Comment: The docker copy does not seem to work for my socket files requirement. Getting error: `ERRO[0000] Can't add file /tmp/mylog to tar: archive/tar: sockets not supported.`  Even if this had worked, it would mean manual creation of files in the host and copying to all instances of the containers. I want to avoid such manual intervention as much as possible.

Comment: post your copy command

Comment: I am creating a socket file like this: `python -c "import socket as s; sock = s.socket(s.AF_UNIX); sock.bind('/tmp/mylog')"`. And copying like this: `docker cp /tmp/mylog 0a09e4709dca:/dev/log`

Comment: that will not work I think you can not do that with sockets