# How to copy a file from the host into a container while starting?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I am trying to build a docker image using the dockerfile, my purpose is to copy a file into a specific folder when i run the "docker run" command!

this my dockerfile code:

```
    FROM openjdk:7

    MAINTAINER MyPerson

    WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp

    ENTRYPOINT ["cp"]

    CMD ["/usr/src/myapp"]

    CMD ls /usr/src/myapp
```

After building my image without any error (using the docker build command), i tried to run my new image:

```
    docker run myjavaimage MainClass.java
```

i got this error: ** cp: missing destination file operand after ‘MainClass.java’ **

How can i resolve this? thx

Comment: your command is cp MainClass.java because of the ENTRYPOINT. what are you trying to do with this ?

Comment: i try to copy the MainClass.java file from the host to the container when it start to run (I want to specify each time the file which will be copied on each docker run command)

Comment: that will not work you need to use volumes or `docker cp` see this for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771529/copy-a-file-to-a-docker-container-just-before-starting-it/57771688#57771688

Comment: I don't think that volumes will help (**because my goal is to copy file from the Host... not the inverse**)! ... and i don't want to execute manually the docker cp command! ...

Comment: you are wrong , volumes will copy the files from your host to the container

Comment: @LinPy I'm not sure about that. I have mounted a 1TB Filestore to my docker container (which def doesn't have 1TB space). Doesn't it simply makes the volume (on the host machine) accessible from within the container, no? Similarly when using `--privileged` makes evth on the host machine accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:7
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
COPY MainClass.java .
RUN javac MainClass.java
ENV CLASSPATH=/usr/src/myapp
CMD java MainClass
```

When you `docker build` this image, it `COPY`s your Java source file from your local directory into the image, compiles it, and sets some metadata telling the JVM where to find the resulting `.class` files.  Then when you launch the container, it will run the single application you've packaged there.

It's common enough to use a higher-level build tool like Maven or Gradle to compile multiple files into a single `.jar` file.  Make sure to `COPY` all of the source files you need in before running the build.  In Java it seems to be common to build the `.jar` file outside of Docker and just `COPY` that in without needing a JDK, and that's a reasonable path too.

In the Dockerfile you show, Docker [combines `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` into a single command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) and runs that command as the single main process of the container.  If you provide a command of some sort at the `docker run` command, that overrides `CMD` but does not override `ENTRYPOINT`.  You only get one `ENTRYPOINT` and one `CMD`, and the last one in the Dockerfile wins.  So you're trying to run container processes like

```sh
# What's in the Dockerfile
cp /bin/sh -c "ls /usr/src/myapp"

# Via your docker run command
cp MainClass.java
```

As @QuintenScheppermans suggests in their answer you can use a `docker run -v` option to inject the file at run time, but this will happen after commands like `RUN javac` have already happened.  You don't really want a workflow where the entire application gets rebuilt every time you `docker run` the container.  Build the image during `docker build` time, or before.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation, but i would like to make it automatically, it means that i want  to pass the file name (MainClass.java) as an argument in the docker run command... (not like that: COPY MainClass.java . ) ... I hope you understood me :)

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

1. You have used `CMD` twice.

`CMD` can only be used once, think of it as the purpose of your docker image. Every time a container is run, it will always execute `CMD` if you want multiple commands, you should use `RUN` and then lastly, used `CMD`

```
FROM openjdk:
MAINTAINER MyPerson
WORKDIR /usr/src/
ENTRYPOINT ["cp"]
RUN /usr/src/myapp
RUN ls /usr/src/myapp
```

2. Copying stuff into image
   There is a simple command `COPY` the syntax being `COPY <from-here> <to-here>`

Seems like you want to run `myjavaimage` so what you will do is

```
COPY /path/to/myjavaimage /myjavaimage
CMD myjavaimage MainClass.java
```

Where you see the arrows, I've just written dummy code. Replace that with the correct code.

Also, your Dockerfile is badly created.

[ENTRYPOINT](https://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/) -> not sure why you'd do "cp", but it's an actual entrypoint. Could point to the root dir of your project or to an app that will be run.
Don't understand why you want to do `ls /usr/src/myapp` but if you do want to do it, use `RUN` and not `CMD`

Lastly, 
Best way to debug docker containers are in interactive mode. That means ssh'ing in to your container, have a look around, run code, and see what is the problem.

Run this: `docker run -it <image-name> /bin/bash` and then have a look inside and it's usually the best way to see what causes issues.

Answer (score 0):

[This stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455036/how-to-copy-file-from-host-to-container-using-dockerfile) perfectly answers your question.

```
COPY foo.txt /data/foo.txt
# where foo.txt is the relative path on host
# and /data/foo.txt is the absolute path in the image
```

If you need to mount a file when running the command:

```
docker run --name=foo -d -v ~/foo.txt:/data/foo.txt -p 80:80 image_name
```

Comment: I want to specify each time the file which will be copied on each docker run command